# Search a text file for a string not working PHP

Tags: php, string, text-files

So In my php code Im trying to have this code check my text file to see it a string exists.  But every time I put the code in whether the string exist or not it echos the code for if the string exists.

```
$addemail = $_POST["subemail"];
$searchfile = file_get_contents("emailist.txt");

if (!strpos($searchfile, "$addemail")) 
{
echo "Your email is already in our database.";
}
else
   {
code to be executed if string doesn't exist.
   }
```

Thanks in advance this really has me stumped :\

Comment: You should _really_ consider using a datebase.

Comment: I haven't learned that yet...Im focusing on learning all the basics before sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your current code does is say "Your email is already in our database." in the event that the email is *not* in the database, or if it's the first email (you should always use the === or !== comparison with strpos). The code should be:

```
$addemail = $_POST['subemail'];
$searchfile = file_get_contents('emailist.txt');

if (strpos($searchfile, $addemail) === false)
{
   //code to be executed if string doesn't exist.
}
else
{
   echo "Your email is already in our database.";
}
```

Comment: +1 for remembering the comparison with false, in case strpos returns a valid 0

Comment: What I was going to say - but I'd also have added a sternly worded warning about using flat text files for storing transactional data with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this syntax:

```
$pos = strpos($searchfile, $addemail);
if ( $pos === false )
{
   ....
}
```

`strpos()` may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE if the position was the 0th (first) character.

Take a look @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the email is not in the searchfile. T

hen your `strpos` will return `false`. When you add the negation in front of an expression evaluated to false it will turn that into true.

So your search for the email address in the file will be true if the email is not in the file. 
You need to remove the negation from the condition.

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that the value of `$addemail` you are checking against is located at the very beginning of your text-file?

[strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) returns the offset of one string within another. Should that string be at the beginning of the other, the index would obviously be `0`. strpos() returns false if the string could not be located. since `0 == false` but `0 !== false`, you might want to change your condition to `if (strpos($searchfile, $addemail) !== false)`.

That being said, you should note that strpos() is case-sensitive. That means `me@EXAMPLE.org` is not found when looking for `me@example.org`. To overcome this, you can use the case-insensitive brother [stripos()](http://php.net/stripos).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($searchfile, "$addemail") === false) {
```

use condition like this...

see this warning...http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues